# How to compute partial derivatives by definition?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

For $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}}, & x\ne0,y\neq0\\
0 & ,x=0,y=0
\end{cases}$$

I'm trying to compute $f_x(0, 0)$ and $f_y(0, 0)$. I'm trying to apply the definition but in both cases I get indeterminate forms:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{h^{2}*0}{h^{4}+0^{2}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^{2}*0}{h^{5}+h*0^{2}}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}{h^{5}}=\frac{0}{0}=?$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0,h)-f(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac{0h}{0+h^{2}}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{0}{h^{3}}=\frac{0}{0}=?$$

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $0$ divided by anything except $0$ is $0$. Also, note that infinite small value is not considered to be $0$. So, you do not get $\cfrac{0}{0}$ but $\cfrac{0}{\text{something very small}}$.

Therefore, your limit is:
$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac 0 h =\lim_{h\to 0} 0 = 0 $$